# C++ - Getting undefined reference to my class

Tags: c++

I have tried to find a solution to my problem online, but I've been unsuccessful. I think my problem may be related to linking.

I have 3 files `scanner.h` , `scanner.cpp` and `scanner_test.h` I've trimmed the files as best I can.

scanner.h

```
class Scanner {
public:
Token *scan (const char *);
};
```

scanner.cpp

```
#include "scanner.h"
Token scan(const char *text){
// Do something code
}
```

scanner_test.h

```
#include "scanner.h"
Scanner *s ;
void test_setup_code ( ) {
    s = new Scanner() ;
}
Token *tks = s->scan ( text ) ; //This line gives the error
```

The error when I try to compile and run is from scanner_test.h `` undefined reference to `Scanner::scan(char const*) ``

This is my understanding of the code:
`scanner_test.h` includes the `scanner.h` file which is linked to `scanner.cpp` during compilation and this file has the definition for `Scanner::scan(char const*)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `scanner.cpp`, you need:

```
Token* Scanner::scan(const char *text) { ... }
//     ^^^^^^^^^
```

otherwise you are implementing a free function called `scan`, not the member method from `Scanner`. (Note I also added the `*` you were missing, but the compiler will tell you this anyways once you added the `Scanner::` part)